# Rails: #inspect not displaying attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am defining `@foo` as a class instance attribute, and using the `after_initialize` callback to set the value of this when a record is created/loaded:

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  @foo = nil

  after_initialize :assign_value

  def assign_value
    @foo = 'bar'
  end
end
```

However, when I `inspect` a Blog object, I am not seeing the `@foo` attribute:

```
 > Blog.first.inspect
=> "#<Blog id: 1, title: 'Test', created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>"
```

What do I need to do to get `inspect` to include this? Or conversely, how does `inspect` determine what to output?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Active record determines which attributes to show in inspect based on the columns in the database table:

```
def inspect
  attributes_as_nice_string = self.class.column_names.collect { |name|
    if has_attribute?(name)
      "#{name}: #{attribute_for_inspect(name)}"
    end
  }.compact.join(", ")
  "#<#{self.class} #{attributes_as_nice_string}>"
end
```

Lifted from [base.rb on github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb)

To change the output of inspect you'll have to overwrite it with your own method e.g.

```
def inspect
  "#{super}, @foo = #{@foo}"
end
```

Which should output:

```
> Blog.first.inspect
=> "#<Blog id: 1, title: 'Test', created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @foo = 'bar'"
```

Comment: Also, I think that you can't call after_initialize with method reference symbol, you have to explicitly create a method called after_initialize (e.g. `def after_initialize; @foo = 'bar'; end`)

Comment: The override was exactly what I was currently trying out with tryruby (damn, that's a hassle). Thanks for releasing me from that :D

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I had no idea that Rails overwrote the Ruby `inspect` method.